# Why does the short rate in the Hull White model follow a normal distribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-calculus, hullwhite

Consider Hull White model $dr(t)=[\theta(t)-\alpha(t)r(t)]dt+\sigma(t)dW(t)$
when we solve the SDE above we have $r(t)=e^{-\alpha t}r(0)+\frac{\theta}{\alpha}(1-e^{-\alpha t})+\sigma e^{-\alpha t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\alpha u}dW(u) $ and when we take expectation and variance we have $r(t) \sim N(e^{-\alpha t}r(0)+\frac{\theta}{\alpha}(1-e^{-\alpha t}),\frac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}(1-e^{-\alpha t}))$.

I know the calculate how find SDE and find expectation or variance but
I don't understand why $r(t)$ has normal distribution.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, we assume that $\alpha$ is a positive constant. You need to show that, for any $t>0$,
\begin{align*}
M_t = \int_0^t e^{\alpha u} dW_u
\end{align*}
is normally distributed, where $\{W_t, \, t \ge 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion with respect to the filtration $\{\mathscr{F}_t,\, t \ge 0\}$.  Here, we employ the time-changed Brownian motion technique. For $t\ge 0$, let $\mathscr{G}_t = \mathscr{F}_{\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+2t)}$. Consider the process $X=\{X_t, t \geq 0\}$, where
\begin{align*}
X_t = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+2t)} e^{\alpha u} dW_u.
\end{align*}
Then $X$ is a continuous martingale with respect to the filtration $\{\mathscr{G}_t,\, t \ge 0\}$. Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
\langle X, X\rangle_t &= \langle M, M\rangle_{\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+2t)}\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+2t)} e^{2u} du =t.
\end{align*}
By Levy's martingale characterization of Brownian motion, $\{X_t, t \ge 0\}$ is a Brownian motion.  That is, for $t >0$, $X_t$ is normally distributed. Consequently, for any $t >0$,
\begin{align*}
M_t &= \int_0^t e^{\alpha u} dW_u\\
&=X_{\frac{1}{2}(e^{2t}-1 )}
\end{align*}
is normally distributed, and $r_t$ is also normally distributed.

Comment: $X_t$ is the product of a function of $t$ and an Ito integral wich is a martingale. How you say that $X_t$ is a martingale too?

Comment: Thanks @ab94. There are indeed some mistakes in the previous answer. See the revision above.

Answer (score 5):

This is a special case of the question of why 
$$ \int_0^T f(t) dW_t $$
is normally distributed for a continuous function $f(t).$  This Ito integral can be approximated by a sum
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} f(i T/N) (W_{(i+1)T/N} - W_{i T/N}) .$$
The Brownian increments $(W_{(i+1)T/N} - W_{i T/N})$ are independent normally distributed random variables.  The key point is that the sum of independent normally distributed variables is again normally distributed.

Comment: The second key point is that if a sequence of normal variable converges in law then the limit is also normal.

Comment: The sum, which is normal, converges to the ito integral in $L^2(P)$, and the key point is that the $L^2$ limit of a sequence of normal random variables is still normal.