# Distribution of stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Suppose that $f(t)$ is a deterministic square integrable function.
I want to show $$\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)dW_{\tau}\sim N(0,\int_{0}^{t}|f(\tau)|^{2}d\tau)$$.

I want to know if the following approach is correct and/or if there's
a better approach.

First note that $$\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)dW_{\tau}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{[t_{i-1},t_{i}]\in\pi_{n}}f(t_{i-1})(W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}})$$
where $\pi_{n}$ is a sequence of partitions of $[0,t]$ with mesh
going to zero. Then $\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)dW_{\tau}$ is a sum of normal
random variables and hence is normal. So all we need to do is calculate
the mean and variance. Firstly: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{[t_{i-1},t_{i}]\in\pi_{n}}f(t_{i-1})(W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}})) & = & \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{[t_{i-1},t_{i}]\in\pi_{n}}f(t_{i-1})E(W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}})\\
 & = & \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{[t_{i-1},t_{i}]\in\pi_{n}}f(t_{i-1})\times0\\
 & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
due to independence of Wiener increments. Secondly: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
var(\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)dW_{\tau}) & = & E((\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)dW_{\tau})^{2})\\
 & = &E( \int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)^{2}d\tau)=\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)^{2}d\tau
\end{eqnarray*}
by Ito isometry.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: The mean is implied by the martingale property of a stochastic integral.

Comment: I think in your very last equation, you can remove sign of expectation($E$), because variance is no longer stochastic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar question has been discussed previously; see [Why does the short rate in the Hull White model follow a normal distribution?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17841/why-does-the-short-rate-in-the-hull-white-model-follow-a-normal-distribution/17863#comment25957_17863).

Basically, the probabilistic limit of normal random variables is still normal.
Then, as $$\sum_{[t_{i-1},t_{i}]\in\pi_{n}}f(t_{i-1})(W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}})$$ is normal, the limit $$\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)dW_{\tau},$$
in probability, is also normal, with the mean and variance as you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t f(\tau) \; dW_\tau \right] = \int_0^t f(\tau) \; \mathbb{E}\left[dW_\tau \right] = 0$, $\int_0^t f(\tau) \; dW_\tau$ has zero mean.

$\text{var}\left( \int_0^t f(\tau) \; dW_\tau \right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\left( \int_0^t f(\tau) \; dW_\tau \right)^2 \right]-\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t f(\tau) \; dW_\tau \right] = \int_0^t f(\tau)^2  d\tau$ using Ito's isometry as stated by others.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to say. How is your answer related to the question?

Comment: I think that this reasoning is true but too short and it is only about the expected value ... we would need more as a full answer